# use ngx translate value with custom component property

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a custom component which has explanation as an input and I try to pass a ngx-translate -translated value here but it doesnt work with the synthax.

```
<app-stats-tile
        explanation = 'Points per Round from Tichu'
></app-stats-tile>
```

I try to do something like this with the pipe

```
explanation = {{ 'Points per Round from Tichu' | translate }}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As @sebaferreras commented, the better option would be without the string interpolation.

```
[title]="'i18n.marketplace.productCard.yourPrice' | translate"
```

Here, `i18n.marketplace.productCard.yourPrice` is my key. Just adding it as answer, so that it may help other users, who don't look at the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

This works:

```
explanation = "{{ 'Text' | translate }}"
```

This does not:

```
explanation = '{{ 'Text' | translate }}'
```

Comment: A better way would actually be `[explanation]= "'Text' | translate"`. String interpolation is recommended to be used only to print data in the template.

Answer (score 0):

in your app.module

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],  //add this
  imports: [
TranslateModule.forRoot({   //add this
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })]
```

then in your custom component

`TranslateModule` add this to your imports array